# Do I need to unit test functions with no control flow?

Tags: unit-testing

I am wondering if I should unit test functions that have no control flow. This functions take some input, call a sequence of 5/6 other functions, then return some output.

Testing them seems a waste of time, since I don't see what I would be testing exactly. The other functions called already have unit test for them. 
The main drawback for me is that I don't know what the output should be a priori, I would need to call the same functions in the test scripit to see if the results coincide; and then what am I testing? That the test function and the actual function have the same lines in the same order?

Thanks for any insight

Note: Same as last question, if you think it's primarily opinion based reformulate as "According to the principles advocated in Art of Unit Testing, should i unit test functions with no control flow?"

Comment: Testing does not test control flow. Testing tests whether or not a function returns correct outputs for certain inputs, that's it. If you are committing to testing, the only way a function does not need tests assuming all its subfunctions are properly covered is if you make an unbreakable promise to yourself that the function will never be edited, ever, no matter what. Are you ready to do that?

Comment: @Amadan True, you're right. Thanks, I will implement them :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes, of course you do!

Long answer: how a method does something is in the end "implementation" detail. In that sense: you should not care at all if a method is using a switch, some if/elses, a loop, or just calls other methods in sequence.

Instead, you should understand the **contract** that your method provides: which input it takes; and what comes out of it (depending on the inputs maybe).

That is what you focus on: creating a setup where your method can run; to then check if the method upholds that contract.

Example:

```
public void foo(Bar bar) {
  FooBar fooBar = bar.wobbel();
  fooBar.throttle();
  fooBar.rattle(this.someField);
}
```

that code above doesn't contain any control flow statements. But still, there are various points in there where things could go wrong (for example NullPointerExceptions). Don't you think it would be better to catch those using unit tests?

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense. Thank you!